# Left outer sql join problems

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to display all the products that do not have a visibility rule with hidden: true. I cant quite figure out the sql. I have the following 4 tables:

```
products:
id: integer
name: string

role:
id: integer
name: string

user_roles:
user_id: integer
role_id: integer

visibility_rules:
hidden: boolean
product: integer
role: text
```

I tried the following

```
SELECT spree_products.* 
FROM spree_products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN spree_visibility_rules ON spree_visibility_rules.product_id
                                        = spree_products.id 
  AND spree_visibility_rules.role_name IN ('Student','Admin') 
  WHERE spree_products.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND (spree_visibility_rules.visible IS NULL)
```

If I have multiple roles (Student & Admin etc) Then I want to find all products that are visible to at least one of the users roles. The problem with the above sql is that it only seems to work if the product is visible to all the users roles. If its hidden to the Student role then it wont return the product even though its visible to the Admin role. I think I have misunderstood Left outer join.

Comment: You should provide actual table definitions that disclose fk references etc. `CREATE TABLE` scripts or what you get with `\d tbl` in psql.

Comment: Do you want a list of visible products for one given `user_id`? Or all visible products for all `users_id` or a list with visible products per `user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visible products for a ***given*** `user_id`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   user_roles       ur
JOIN   role             r  ON r.id = ur.role_id
JOIN   visibility_rules vr ON vr.role = r.id
JOIN   spree_products   p  ON p.id = vr.product
WHERE  ur.user_id = 123   -- given user_id
AND    NOT vr.hidden
GROUP  BY p.id;           -- must be defined as PK
```

Depending on details, performance might be optimized further.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subselect instead.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  spree_products
WHERE
  id IN (
    SELECT
      product_id
    FROM
      spree_visibility_rules
    WHERE
      NOT hidden
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sp.id,sp.name,svr.hidden from spree_products sp
inner join spree_visibility_rules svr
on sp.id = svr.product
where svr.hidden = 0
```